# Parse tree not displaying when using the NLTK ChartParser with a custom grammar

Tags: parsing, nlp, nltk

I am trying to generate NLTK parse trees, however my defined grammar does not produce an error nor display a parse tree. An example sentence and my code is given below. Any hints on how to produce a parse tree with my defined grammar would be much appreciated.

Example sentence:

```
"The big black dog barked at the cat and chased away."
```

My code (I am unsure why it does not work):

```py
from IPython.display import display
import nltk
#nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk import ChartParser
import string

punctuation = list(string.punctuation)

tokens = [token for token in tokens if token not in punctuation]

print(tokens)

grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring(
    """
    S -> NP VP
    NP -> DT NOM | ADJ ADJ NN 
    NM -> ADJ NOM | ADJ NN | ADJ ADJ NN
    VP -> VP VP | V PP | CC VP | V RB | V
    PP -> IN DT NN
    
    DT -> 'The' | 'the'
    ADJ -> 'big' | 'black'
    NN -> 'dog' | 'cat'
    V -> 'barked' | 'chased'
    RB -> 'away'
    IN -> 'at'
    CC -> 'and'
    """
)

parser = ChartParser(grammar)

for tree in parser.parse(tokens):
    display(tree)
    print("Tree displayed")
```